# Emacs evil-mode C-c/C-x to "cc"/"cx". ( key translation)

Tags: key-bindings, evil

I read in evil wiki that I can change prefix keys such as `C-c` or `C-x` and so on to `cc`, `cx`, but I'm not experienced in Elisp and I tried a lot of variants but I can only define `c` as `C-c` but not a `cc` to `C-c` here is my `evil.el` file. What do I need to change in my `evil.el` or maybe in `init.el` to set `cc` as `C-c` and `cx` as `C-x`?

My `evil.el` file:

```
  (defvar evilPackages
  '(goto-chg
    evil-magit
    evil-matchit
    evil-escape))

(mapc #'(lambda (package)
    (unless (package-installed-p package)
      (package-install package)))
      evilPackages)

;; Undo-tree (as dependency of Evil)
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/undo-tree")
(global-undo-tree-mode)

(use-package evil
  :ensure t
  :init
  (setq evil-want-C-u-scroll t)
  (setq evil-want-integration t) ;; This is optional since it's already set to t by default.
  (setq evil-want-keybinding nil)
  (require 'evil-magit)
  (require 'evil-matchit)
  (global-evil-matchit-mode 1)
 :config
  (evil-mode 1)
  (setq-default evil-escape-key-sequence "jk")
  (evil-escape-mode t))

(use-package evil-collection
  :after evil
  :ensure t
  :config
  (evil-collection-init))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, I recommend to avoid key translating in emacs. I know it's common in vim but in emacs I think it's better to map your actions using modes and commands. That's because, in contrast to vim, everything in emacs is a command, so you don't really need to rely on key translation. You can check which command a key stroke is bound to with `F1 k [key]`. If you specify the reasons you need to do this we might help you with a better solution.

That said, the following code should do what you wish:

```
(defun my/c-c ()
  (interactive)
  (setq unread-command-events (listify-key-sequence (kbd "C-c"))))

(defun my/c-x ()
  (interactive)
  (setq unread-command-events (listify-key-sequence (kbd "C-x"))))

(evil-define-key 'normal global-map (kbd "cc") 'my/c-c)
(evil-define-key 'normal global-map (kbd "cx") 'my/c-x)
```

EDIT: If you want to rebind all ctrl keys, you could loop thourgh all the letters and map them like this:

```
(defun my/c-bind (letter)
  (let* ((l letter))
    (evil-define-key 'normal global-map (concat "c" letter)
      `(lambda () (interactive)
         (setq unread-command-events
               (listify-key-sequence (kbd (concat "C-" ',l))))))))

;; bind all looping from a to z
(defun my/c-bind-all()
  (let ((char 97))
    (while (< char 123)
      (my/c-bind (char-to-string char))
      (setq char (+ char 1)))))

(my/c-bind-all)
```

If you don't want every ctrl combination rebound, instead of using `my/c-bind-all` you could also bind keys individually with `my/c-bind`:

```
(my/c-bind "c") ;; bind 'cc' to ctrl-c
(my/c-bind "x") ;; bind 'cx' to ctrl-x
```

Comment: It's pretty good and works fine, but I expected something like cx where x can be any character, like super() in normal global-map, to avoid using C-c C-g C-x and so on, because its hard for hands to do it all day, my keys were rebind to caps_lock or to cmd or to any other key, anyway its really hard for hands.

Comment: @om2c0de I edited my answer with a dynamic solution. Is that what you need?

Comment: Wow, you are like the elisp ninja!! Of course, this bounty will be yours, just last question - Does it really complex to watch for c(pressed)  events like C-x f can be a cxf ?

Comment: Nah, I'm a elisp beginner. I just learn as I go, no rush. I don't understand your question. You mean `cxf` to be `C-x C-f`? Because `cxf` already should behave like `C-x f`

Comment: Yeah,  so if  i'm pressing "c" => c-x c-f as cxf, but if I just pressed once "c" => cxf as C-x f, Do you understand me? ;)

Comment: The easiest way is to bind `C-x f` to find like this: `(define-key global-map (kbd "C-x f") 'find-file)`. I think this would have to be done manually because Emacs has a lot of keybindings after `C-x` or `C-c`, and some have ctrl and others don't.

Comment: @om2c0de but, instead of doing this approach, I would recommend you something like [spacemacs](http://spacemacs.org/). Almost all actions are triggered with space by default, without using the ctrl key

Comment: Yeah, I know about spacemacs, maybe it's really my variant, I still don,t know how emacs users can write a lot of code without any pain in hands

Comment: Personally, I maintain my own emacs configuration, where I've setup my own bindings in the spacemacs style, so I don't need to use ctrl at all if I don't want to. Like finding file for me is `SPC f f`, switching buffer `SPC SPC`. Every time I catch myself doing pressing some ctrl command I like to write some evil bindings for it. I think it's better than just blindingly "converting" emacs keystrokes to the "c" key. I also remapped my capslock key to act as ctrl, so it gets easier to use ctrl whenever I need, even outside emacs.