# spacemacs - rebind existing keys

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, evil

I am trying to rebind <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd> key as well as capital <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>Y</kbd>, but cannot get them to work. Any pointers?

I put this into my `.spacemacs` (in `dotspacemacs/user-config`):

```
(evil-define-key 'normal key-translation-map (kbd "j") (kbd "gj"))
(evil-define-key 'normal key-translation-map (kbd "k") (kbd "gk"))
(evil-define-key 'normal key-translation-map (kbd "Y") (kbd "y$"))
(evil-define-key 'normal key-translation-map (kbd "B") (kbd "^"))
(evil-define-key 'normal key-translation-map (kbd "E") (kbd "$"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from [this somewhat related answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/48572/18569), here's the pattern you should follow:

```
(evil-define-key 'normal global-map (kbd "B") (kbd "^"))
```